# bAutoWidth not working when dataTable.bootstrap.js is included in the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

'bAutoWidth : false' , is not working when dataTable.bootstrap.js is included in the webpage. I need dataTable.bootstrap.js in my page for design. How to resolve this?

```js
$('#table').DataTable({
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [-1],
            "orderable": false
        }]
});
```

Comment: Remove default `jquery.dataTables.css`, it is not needed when you use `dataTables.bootstrap.js` / `dataTables.bootstrap.css` and I guess that is causing the conflict (whatever "not working" means)

Comment: Removing jquery.dataTables.css was not helpful. By 'not working' I meant, I can't remove the Auto Width set by dataTables even when bAutoWidth is given false. In my table, width is still being set for table head(th).

Comment: OK. Sounds weird. Can you replicate this in a fiddle ...? Here is a starting point (just add bootstrap) http://jsfiddle.net/hqf4wrpq/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mrkais/L8vtwjps/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using `autoWidth: false` only makes sense when you're setting your own column width with [`columns.width`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) option or via HTML/CSS.

Also you're using words with no spaces which affects the width of all columns. Using `table-layout: fixed` on the table may help.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/L8vtwjps/2/) for code and demonstration.